# extract images from email

Tags: php, imap

I need to generate HTML files with additional images from emails

All data is fetched with `php_imap`

## img tag in email

```
<img alt="" src="cid:part3.08050603.09060803@example.com">
```

I got multiple `img` tags, but how to extract the actual image part `cid:part3.08050603.09060803@example.com` from the email and save it as a file?

Comment: You need to parse the MIME data, you'd need an external MIME parser library for PHP.

Answer (score 1):

#### Grabbing the image source

You can do this by using [`DomDocument`](http://php.net/domdocument) and [`DOMXpath`](http://php.net/domxpath) to query for the image `src`.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($email); //load the string into DOMDocument   
$selector = new DOMXPath($doc); //create a new domxpath instance
$images = $selector->query('//img/@src'); //Query the image tag and get the src
foreach ($images as $item) {
   echo $item->value; //grab the value (output: cid:part3.08050603.09060803@example.com)
}
```

https://eval.in/477064

#### Saving as a file

Now that you've grabbed the image source, you can just write the contents to a file. This does mean you'll need `allow_url_fopen` on.

```
foreach ($images as $item) {
   $content = file_get_contents($item->value);
   file_put_contents('./'.str_replace("/", "-", ltrim(parse_url($item->value)['path'],'/')), $content );
}
```

Having the `foreach` [supports multiple images within the e-mail body](https://eval.in/477069)

Comment: I need to get the data part.. not the html tags :)

Comment: or if you can answer both questions.. it would be great.. but the primary problem is to get the image data and save the data as files

Comment: How would the HTML parser know where the cid: images are?  These are references that have to be filled in by the viewer to the actual attachments.  The attachments have Content-ID: headers that need to be matched up with these.

Comment: You cant get the file data like that just from a string.. You need to fetch the data from the imap resource

Answer (score 0):

## Extract the images from the email

http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-email-extract-inline-image-attachments/